How to send transaction with same hash miltiple times?
I am trying to make a tool to bulk transfer SOL between wallets.

Example:
I have 1 main wallet and 5 wallet where I should send sol I send
transaction and waiting for it to be confirmed for 5 seconds. If it is
not confirmed, I send another transaction

My goal is to send a bunch of transactions and make it to only one of them be finalized, so I won't need to check if any of them is confirmed.
How to do it (Im using web3js)?
